# Does the WITH clause have a performance impact

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have found that the WITH clause makes my queries more readable and easier to compose with other queries. I it safe to use this clause liberally or could it have a performance impact?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no performance impact, actually you can use it to improve performance.

E.g. when you have a long MATCH path which has a high fan-out but you're only interested in the distinct values at the end of the path then you can use:

```
MATCH ....
WITH distinct n3
MATCH (n3)-....
```

to reduce the work-in-progress data that Neo4j has to look at for the next MATCH.

You can always check your query execution plans with the PROFILE prefix and compare the version with and without `WITH`.